# Mark a position on a drawn line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to mark a position along trajectory lines I'm drawing. The marking should be in roughly the same position, say X% of the length of the line.

My current code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \definecolor{edge}{RGB}{135,206,250}
    \definecolor{asphalt}{RGB}{153,153,153}
    \definecolor{marker}{RGB}{144,238,144}
    

    \coordinate (step_right) at (1.5,0);
    \coordinate (step_up) at (0,0.5);
    \coordinate (car_height) at (0,0.3);
    
    \coordinate (E0) at (2,1.5);
    \coordinate (E1) at ($(E0) + 2*(step_right)$);
    \coordinate (E11) at ($(E1) + (step_up)$);
    \coordinate (E12) at ($(E1) - (step_up)$);£
    \coordinate (E2) at ($(E1) + 2*(step_right)$);
    \coordinate (E21) at ($(E2) + (step_up)$);
    \coordinate (E22) at ($(E2) - (step_up)$);
    \coordinate (E3) at ($(E2) + 2*(step_right)$);
    
    
    \fill[asphalt] (0,0) rectangle ++(15,3);
    

    \draw[edge, ultra thick] (E0) .. controls ($(E0) + (step_right)$) and ($(E1) - (step_right)$) .. (E1);
    \draw[edge, ultra thick] (E0) .. controls ($(E0) + (step_right)$) and ($(E11) - (step_right)$) .. (E11);
    \draw[edge, ultra thick] (E0) .. controls ($(E0) + (step_right)$) and ($(E12) - (step_right)$) .. (E12);
    
    \draw[edge, ultra thick] (E1) .. controls ($(E1) + (step_right)$) and ($(E2) - (step_right)$) .. (E2);
    \draw[edge, ultra thick] (E1) .. controls ($(E1) + (step_right)$) and ($(E21) - (step_right)$) .. (E21);
    \draw[edge, ultra thick] (E1) .. controls ($(E1) + (step_right)$) and ($(E22) - (step_right)$) .. (E22);
    
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (ego) at ($(E0) - (car_height)$) {\includegraphics[width=.05\textwidth, angle=-90, origin=c]{images/methodology/car_blue}};
    %\draw (E) -- (E1) node [circle, midway, fill=white] {};    
    
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces:

[image: Current Figure]

I would like to have something like this:

[image: Desired Figure]

What the markers look like is not so strict, I'm happy to adjust. But they have to mark a concrete position. I've tried maybe using a label that is positioned `midway` to achieve this, but I don't know if it can be applied to the spline curves I'm using.

Additionally, I would like to add white and red striped bounds, like they have them in [Formula 1 races](https://www.google.com/search?q=formula%201%20eau%20rouge&sxsrf=ALeKk02OMGmY-dtfmsN2mAfKhfZujROgJw:1620322599824&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjblO-HzLXwAhUCwKQKHf_4D2wQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1600&bih=785#imgrc=GJcRSGw4yNSsMM). I'm not sure what the best approach to this would be.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I didn't really understand where and how you'd like the red and white strip bands, so I just answered the main question. Feel free to ask your second question independantly, whenever you feel happy with answers here about the main topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to use the `decorations.markings` library, with an arrow tip decoration, positionned at 0.75.

[image: markings on a line]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings}

\tikzset{mymark/.style={
            decoration={ markings,mark=at position 0.75 with{\arrow[blue,line width=1.5pt]{|}};}},
        markedsegment/.style={mymark,postaction={decorate}}}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \definecolor{edge}{RGB}{135,206,250}
    \definecolor{asphalt}{RGB}{153,153,153}
    \definecolor{marker}{RGB}{144,238,144}
    

    \coordinate (step_right) at (1.5,0);
    \coordinate (step_up) at (0,0.5);
    \coordinate (car_height) at (0,0.3);
    
    \coordinate (E0) at (2,1.5);
    \coordinate (E1) at ($(E0) + 2*(step_right)$);
    \coordinate (E11) at ($(E1) + (step_up)$);
    \coordinate (E12) at ($(E1) - (step_up)$);
    \coordinate (E2) at ($(E1) + 2*(step_right)$);
    \coordinate (E21) at ($(E2) + (step_up)$);
    \coordinate (E22) at ($(E2) - (step_up)$);
    \coordinate (E3) at ($(E2) + 2*(step_right)$);
    
    
    \fill[asphalt] (0,0) rectangle ++(15,3);
    
    
    \draw[edge, ultra thick] (E0) .. controls ($(E0) + (step_right)$) and ($(E1) - (step_right)$) .. (E1);
    \draw[edge, markedsegment,ultra thick] (E0) .. controls ($(E0) + (step_right)$) and ($(E11) - (step_right)$) .. (E11);
    \draw[edge, markedsegment,ultra thick] (E0) .. controls ($(E0) + (step_right)$) and ($(E12) - (step_right)$) .. (E12);
    
    \draw[edge, ultra thick] (E1) .. controls ($(E1) + (step_right)$) and ($(E2) - (step_right)$) .. (E2);
    \draw[edge, markedsegment,ultra thick] (E1) .. controls ($(E1) + (step_right)$) and ($(E21) - (step_right)$) .. (E21);
    \draw[edge, markedsegment,ultra thick] (E1) .. controls ($(E1) + (step_right)$) and ($(E22) - (step_right)$) .. (E22);
    
   
    
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If you want to be able to place your mark *on the fly*, you can modify a bit your tikzstyle like this:

```
\tikzset{mymark/.style={
            decoration={ markings,mark=at position #1 with{\arrow[blue,line width=1.5pt]{|}};}},
        markedsegment/.style={mymark=#1,postaction={decorate}}}
```

And call it like this:

```
    \draw[edge, ultra thick] (E0) .. controls ($(E0) + (step_right)$) and ($(E1) - (step_right)$) .. (E1);
    \draw[edge, markedsegment=0.75,ultra thick] (E0) .. controls ($(E0) + (step_right)$) and ($(E11) - (step_right)$) .. (E11);
    \draw[edge, markedsegment=0.5,ultra thick] (E0) .. controls ($(E0) + (step_right)$) and ($(E12) - (step_right)$) .. (E12);
    
    \draw[edge, ultra thick] (E1) .. controls ($(E1) + (step_right)$) and ($(E2) - (step_right)$) .. (E2);
    \draw[edge, markedsegment=0.85,ultra thick] (E1) .. controls ($(E1) + (step_right)$) and ($(E21) - (step_right)$) .. (E21);
    \draw[edge, markedsegment=0.9,ultra thick] (E1) .. controls ($(E1) + (step_right)$) and ($(E22) - (step_right)$) .. (E22);
```

Which produces this:

[image: markings on the fly]

Comment: Looks perfect, thanks a lot Seb!